# $\iint_A\nabla\times\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS$ with $\nabla\times\textbf{u}$ known.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

> Let $$\textbf{v}=\operatorname{curl}\textbf{u}= (-2+43x-86y+43z, 3-2x+4y-2z, 2-47x+94y-47z)$$ and let $A$ be the part of $z(x,y)=9-x^2-9y^2$ that is above the plane $z(x,y)=x+45y+\frac{113}{2}$. Now calculate $$\iint_A\nabla\times\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS$$

A hint is given to use Stoke's theorem twice.

So my take is: $$\iint_A\nabla\times\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS=\iint_A\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS=\int_{\partial A} \nabla\times \textbf{v} \cdot d\textbf{r}$$

So I get $d\textbf{r}$ as the boundary to an ellipse that satisfies $1=(\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{3})^2+(y+\frac{5}{2})^2$, so we have $\textbf{r}=(x,y,(\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{3})^2+(y+\frac{5}{2})^2)$ and
$\nabla\times\textbf{v}= (96,90,84)$

I am not sure  how to proceed from here. Should I parametrize $\textbf{r}$ in terms of trig functions?c

Comment: Why is $\iint_A\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\int_{\partial A}\nabla\times\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$?

Comment: Huh?  You should only get $\int_{\partial A}\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$ from Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Typically when Stokes is used twice, the first step is to convert from a surface integral over $A$ to a line integral over $\partial A$. You've done that. The second step is to use Stokes again to get back to a surface integral---but this time, over some other surface $A'$. This $A'$ needs to have the same boundary as $A$, but beyond that is simply chosen to make the flux of $\nabla\times \mathbf{u}$ as simple to compute as possible. (For instance, it'd be much more convenient if $\hat{n}$ always pointed in the same direction...)

Comment: To be honest one should use divergence theorem once instead of Stokes' twice

Comment: @user10354138 we are talking about surface integral of curl of a vector field. Can you please elaborate what you mean by applying divergence theorem?

Comment: @MathLover curl of a vector field is itself a vector field, so divergence theorem together with div of a curl is zero gives $(\iint_{A_1}+\iint_{A_2})\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\iiint_V\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ when $\partial V=A_1\cup A_2$.  Here $V$ is the region between the plane and the paraboloid, $A_1=A$ and $A_2$ is the the ellipse on the plane, with $\mathbf{n}$ oriented say outward from $V$.

Comment: @user10354138 yes agree and that is what the problem translates to using Stokes' theorem twice as well.

Comment: @MathLover No, it only uses divergence theorem once, so is slightly cleaner and there is no confusion about orientation of $\mathbf{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint essentially means that you should translate this to another surface (with the same boundary curve) than the one you currently have. In other words,

$\displaystyle \iint_{S} (\nabla\times\textbf{u})\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS = \int_{C} \textbf{u}\cdot d\textbf{r} = \iint_{S_1} (\nabla\times\textbf{u})\cdot \textbf{n}\ dS$.

The boundary curve of the elliptic paraboloid surface, as you correctly found, is -

$\displaystyle (\frac{x+0.5}{3})^2+(y+2.5)^2 = 1, z = 9 - x^2 - 9y^2$.

Now using Stokes' Theorem a second time, we can equate line integral of the vector field along the boundary curve to the surface integral of the curl of $\textbf{u}$ over elliptic disk given by,

$\displaystyle (\frac{x+0.5}{3})^2+(y+2.5)^2 \leq 1, z = x + 45y + \frac{113}{2}$.

$\nabla \times \textbf{u}= (-2+43x-86y+43z, 3-2x+4y-2z, 2-47x+94y-47z)$

For the dot product, use the fact that normal vector to the plane is $(-1, -45, 1)$ and **the dot product is simply $-131$**.

So your task is just finding the area of the ellipse. You can, **Either** use the formula $\pi ab$ for area of the ellipse and multiply by $131$ which gives you answer of $-393 \pi$. **Or** you can do the integral as below.

Use substitution, $x = - 0.5 + 3r \cos\theta, y = -2.5 + r \sin\theta$ for the surface integral, $0 \leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and plug in Jacobian $3r$ instead of usual $r$. That is $3$ times the area of a unit circle( = $3 \pi$).